# Jasmine testing a service

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs5

I'm trying to make a service return an error.

I'm mocking the service, using rxjs _throw and then testing if a router navigate function has been executed.

But the router navigate function should fire only if the HttpErrorResponse object has the value errorMessage: 'Session not found'

The entire object should be `{error: {error: errorMessage: 'Session not found'}}}`

I've used the mock service before, but I'm having issues getting it to return an error and behave the same as the actual function in the component

The component function:

```
this.sub = this.addressService.getAddress(postcode.replace(/\s+/g, ''), houseNo)
          .subscribe((response: AddressResponse) => {

            if (response.getAddressFromPostcodeResponse &&
                response.getAddressFromPostcodeResponse.address &&
                response.getAddressFromPostcodeResponse.address.length > 0) {

                  this.yourAddressDetails.addressDetails.placeholder = 'Please select';
                  this.yourAddressDetails.addressDetails.options = this.addressService.setAddressDetails(response.getAddressFromPostcodeResponse.address);
            } else {
                  this.yourAddressDetails.addressDetails.options = [];
                  this._noPostcodeMatch = true;
            }
          }, error => {

                 this.yourAddressDetails.addressDetails.options = [];
                 this.httpPostcodeError = true;

            if (error.error && error.error.errorMessage === 'Session not found') {
                 this.router.navigate([`${this.journeyService.type}/${FeatureType.SessionTimeout}`]);
            }
         });
```

The test:

```
it('should navigate to session-timeout component if no session.', () => {
    mockAddressService.getAddress.and.returnValue(_throw({error : {
      error: {
        errorMessage: 'Session not found'
      }
     }}));
     spyOn(component['router'], 'navigate');
    expect(component['router'].navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['quote/session-timeout']);
  });
```

There are other variables being set in that part of the component code `httpPostcodeError` that I've tested to see if being set but, they are not, so it seems it does not execute that statement.

I get `Expected spy navigate was not called`

Comment: Have you tried to return throwError from rxjs instead of _throw? Have a look at this simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/location-and-test-qu2y32

Comment: Thanks, but I get errors when trying to import throwError as you have done it, 
"This import is blacklisted, import a submodule instead"
I'm no expert but is that rxjs 5 and I'm using 6?

Comment: the import should be `import {Observable, of, throwError} from 'rxjs';` its rxjs 6.4.0. how does your import look like?

Comment: my apologies I'm using 5, I've updated the tag attached to my question, my import is the same as yours, however, is this the reason I'm getting errors?

Comment: ah ok. i'll change my stackblitz and have a look again.

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz. I used Observable.throw instead of throwError. Have you tried that?

Comment: I just tried, but it didn't work, I'm sure I tried earlier today and had the same result, 
when I log the error object in the component when I'm running test the error.error object is always undefined

Comment: Could you please recreate your error in a stackblitz? Then it's easier to help. Feel free to work mine and change it accordingly.